# Is that good for performance to include same file of "view" in a huge loop?

Tags: php, performance, templates

Tell me please how do you think: is there large difference of performance of doing next things?

1. Controller doing `foreach()` of huge array (for example array of 10 000 menu elements) and on each iteration includes view of `<li><?=$var;?></li>` and doing echo of variable inside that view.
2. Controller include once view file. View has `foreach()` loop inside.

Does server caches request to that view file and performance between 1st and 2nd way will be almost same? What must I to prefer: more view files and clearer less code inside view or not?

Comment: If your change makes it easier to read the code, I'd split it up even if it makes it slower. Don't forget that you don't always need to optimise: only spend time making it faster if it is actually slow in practice. If your users are happy with the speed, don't optimise!

Comment: Usually there is no php code (only php variables) at all in the view part.

Comment: is the file your including unique in each iteration

Comment: @CodingInsane, no - not unique!

Comment: Is this your whole code? Then you could divide this in 3 parts: the first view `<li>`, the variable and the second view `</li>`. You would need to load every view only once and could use it for each iteration of the loop

Comment: Also important: What template engines did you test and how did they perform?

Comment: @kingkero While refactoring one project I try to optimize few algorithms. And see code of 2 modules, what are developed maybe by two different people. One module use a lot of views, other use few views with some loops inside and some functions inside too. And after this I try to understand what developer are more righter, which code is better and what is faster.

Comment: @kingkero Kohana::View(); it has method render(); which include view file